# Check for MySQL connection during a loop

Tags: c++

Greetings, I have a C++ script that runs indefinitely.  Sometimes (rarely), the MySQL connection is lost, so I'd like to implement some logic to reconnect if that ever happens. I know this is easy, but I just want to ensure that it's correct as I'm new to C++.

This is how the connection is established:

```
  const char* mysql_server        = argv[argcounter++];
  const char* mysql_database      = argv[argcounter++];
  const char* mysql_user          = argv[argcounter++];
  const char* mysql_password      = argv[argcounter++];

  mysql_conn = mysql_init(NULL);

  // connect to database
  if (!mysql_real_connect(mysql_conn, mysql_server,
       mysql_user, mysql_password, mysql_database, 0, NULL, 0))
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(mysql_conn));
    exit(1);
  }
```

I'm wondering how to check if the connection no longer exists. The loop runs every 1500 seconds.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the MYSQL reconnection option to mysql_options?

From  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-options.html) :-

"MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT (argument type: my_bool *)

Enable or disable automatic reconnection to the server if the connection is found to have been lost. Reconnect has been off by default since MySQL 5.0.3; this option is new in 5.0.13 and provides a way to set reconnection behavior explicitly."